# How to use a list 2 times i javascript

Tags: javascript, match, google-ads-api

With the script below, I find a number of keywords with AdWordsApp.keywords() based on some parameters.
Once these words are found, they must be paused.

**My question is the following:**
How can I use the same list of ExactKeywords, that I have already found, to activate the same keyword in another campaign with a different name than CampaignName?

---

```
   var Exact_CampaignName = "CampaignName_1";
    
    function main() {
      // Getting list of keywords with cliks
      var kw_Conv_Exact = AdWordsApp.keywords()
        .withCondition("Click >= 50")
        .withCondition("Status = ENABLED")
        .withCondition(Exact_CampaignName)
        .get();
        
     
      // Get Keywords from Campaigns_1
      var ExactKeywords = [];
      while (kw_Conv_Exact.hasNext()) {
        var kw_exact = kw_Conv_Exact.next();
        ExactKeywords.push(kw_exact);
      
      
        // Pause exaxt keywords.
        for(var i in ExactKeywords) {
          ExactKeywords[i].pause();
        }

 

//But how do I enable the same keywords from var ExactKeywords = [] but in another campaign_2???


     }
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does pause() do? Is ExactKeywords a reserved name or could we call it anything?

Comment: A keyword can be either Eligible or Paused. When the script activates Pause () then the status of the keyword is paused.

ExactKeywords can be anything. I need the ExactKeywords list to be updated daily so that all the paused keywords in Campaigns_1 can be activated in Campaigns_2.

Comment: Why not just make a second copy?

Comment: @DCR you will elaborate?
Where do I declare the list from ExactKeywords to be used on another campaign?

Answer (score 0):

why not just make a copy?

```js
var ExactKeywords = [];
var ExactKeywords2=[];
      while (kw_Conv_Exact.hasNext()) {
        var kw_exact = kw_Conv_Exact.next();
        ExactKeywords.push(kw_exact);
        ExactKeywords2.push(kw_exact);
```

Comment: This script pauses keywords in campaign_1 and then activates them again in campaign_1

But the script should pause keywords in campaign_1 and then re-enable them in campaign_2

`code`
// Now go through each one and pause keyword in Campaign_1. for(var i in ExactKeywords) { ExactKeywords[i].pause(); } 

// Now go through each one and enable them in Campaign_2. for(var i in ExactKeywords2) { ExactKeywords2[i].enable(); }
`code`